# Can I return my MacBook Pro?

Tags: macbook-pro, mac

I just bought a new Mac from the Apple online store (six days ago) and it had a scratch on it when I got it. I would return it, but I needed my Mac for work, so I waited four days. And in the four days my Mac got another scratch.

Can I return it now?

Comment: I just looked in your original... I just got a new Mac (6 days ago) and it had a scratch on it when I got it. I would return it, but I needed my Mac for work, so i waited 4 days. And in the 3 days my mac got another scratch....!!!!! It had no Apple online store, so I was responding to that before your edit.

Comment: Yes, I know. I added it because you asked for it. Sorry I forgot to write it in the comment.

Answer (score 1):

In europe you can always return things bought online for 14 days. Your scratch will change that of course, best call Apple to ask about it.

I had a mac that had a dent on arrival once. I went to my local apple authorized repair center and they were apple changed the part for no charge.

Answer (score 0):

Where do you live? Return policies vary by region. Also, the severity of the scratches will play into if they will take it back or not.

The best way to get an answer is to go to an Apple Store and ask them.

The second best way is to use your 90-days of phone support and ask by phone.